# Jmeter - Regular expression extractor - multiple random variable

Tags: random, jmeter

Jmeter 2.9

I am using Regex Extractor to extractor to extract a list of ids from a response message and write them to a variable *idList*.

Using beanshell, I want to extract multiple random items from the list.

If *n* is my random position in the list, then I am trying to extract the value from the *idList* using

```
String id = "${idList_" + n + "}";
s = ${__V(id)};
```

If n is 7 then this returns ${idList_7} rather than the value at idList_7.

I have also tried

```
String id = "idList_" + n;
s = ${__V(id)};
```

but this returns idList_7 rather than the value.

I have also tried using *__eval*.

Can yo help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a pre-defined variable `vars`

For example if you have a variable called `idList_7` which contains some value you can access the value using following Beanshell code

```
String s = vars.get("idList_7");
```

or if you want to use concatenation

```
int seven = 7;
String s = vars.get("idLst_" + seven);
```

See [How to use Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed explanation on JMeter components which are exposed to Beanshell.